# Discord bot not playing any audio and immediately terminates once joined channel (Python)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I am trying to create a small discord bot for me and my friends. Currently, I tried several examples online for a music bot using ffmpeg. I added the path to environment variables as well. I simplified the code to make it easier to debug. Below is the code:

```
voice_client = await msg.author.voice.channel.connect()
print(voice_client.is_playing())
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options': '-vn'}
voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source="test.mp3", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

The moment the bot enters the channel, it displays this on the terminal and nothing else happens:
`discord.player ffmpeg process 18792 successfully terminated with return code of 2880417800`

I originally tried Youtube videos, but that did not work. So, I tried local files, and that did not work as well. Tried bypassing the ffmpeg path using `executable = "C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe"`, still the same error. Is there some other reasons for the error such as firewalls etc? I have set the intents to all(). Could that be a problem as well?

Comment: So it doesn't reach `print(voice_client.is_playing())` ?

Comment: It reaches the `print(voice_client.is_playing())`, returning false. I added another `print(voice_client.is_playing())` after `voice_client.play()` function, and that too returned false.

Comment: maybe `play()` is async too, so it will not update the state immediately. Do you have any docs link? As I don't know this client but maybe can check some parameters, lifecycle etc.

Comment: I referred to multiple youtube tutorial videos and followed 1:1. Somehow I still get the error. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8wxin72h50

Comment: I think this is the player: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#voiceclient. I'd recommend always check the official API reference/guide in such cases, to understand all the params, possible errors etc. You could start with checking other methods like `is_connected` to get more info on what's happening. And maybe setting the `after` callback in the `play()` would give more details on the error.

Comment: There's also a link to examples on the main docs page. Maybe you'll find something suitable there

Comment: Can you try without the `**FFMPEG_OPTIONS`?

Comment: It worked when i remove the `FFMPEG_OPTIONS`. Thanks a bunch!